# Binding large amount of data on a combo box causes performance problems

Tags: asp.net, combobox, drop-down-menu, updatepanel

I have a large amount of data about 5000 to 6000 records.

I bind all these records on a combo box.

The problem is that the combo box is slow, with delays in expanding and selecting and sometimes hangs the page entirely.

Is there any solution to this problem, or an alternative control even?

I also tried `RadComboBox`, but resulted in the same problem.

Comment: Is it worthy to have that many records on a single combo box? I can't understand how someone would want to navigate through that many items...

Comment: hmmm , i know but this is a requirement .

Comment: Prioser's suggestion is good and gave me an idea. You can "split" all the records in a more reasonable quantity, for example split them by start letter, or a group.

Comment: You are hitting a limitation of the web browser. It will be slower on the customers machine. Users usually don't have computers as powerful as development machines. I would suggest working with your stakeholders and revising the spec due to technical limitations. When customers ask for drop down lists, combo boxes, or multi select list boxes they usually don't actually care how the UX is implemented. What they are really want is a simple and efficient user interface. If they are adamant about using drop downs then try filtering the data based on some type of context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way around this is to use a solution found [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/populatingwithdata/autocompletesql/defaultcs.aspx). The reason is that you are creating DOM elements for each row, which causes the browser to get a little resource hungry.

Loading the rows as required may be the only option for you.